# Is it possible to draw GDI objects in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, gdi

I have a user control made to use with winform applications. The basic functions is to draw and modify GDI objects and save it to database. Now my organisation is planning to develop web application for the same purpose. Now I am searching a method to draw gdi objects on a asp panel. If anybody have any idea, please share with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw using GDI in ASP.NET in a Bitmap object. Obviously you cannot draw on the client screen. If you want the image to be displayed you should save it and serve it to the client in an img tag. However using GDI in ASP.NET environment is not recommended. If I remember correctly the reason was multithreading issues.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Drawing namespace gives access to GDI+ functionalities.